# Access module method directly without operator ('.' or '::')

Tags: ruby, methods, module

I am trying to build a module that can be included in any class and its methods be invoked directly.

The ruby gem [colored](https://github.com/defunkt/colored) is a great example. For example, I can invoke the method from the `Colored` module at any place just by doing something like `puts "I am the color blue!".blue` Though, that isn't any class. But I noticed that they invoke `String.send(:include, Colored)`.

Any insight is appreciated.

**Goal:**

```
module Example
  def do_something
    puts 'foo!'
  end
end

# Instead of calling Example::do_something or Example.do_something,
# I want to do this:
do_something # => 'foo!'
```

**(Incorrect way)**

```
module Example
  extend self 

  def do_something
    puts 'foo!'
  end
end

do_something # => undefined local variable or method `do_something' for main:Object (NameError)
```

**(Another incorrect way)**

```
module Example
  extend self # not sure...

  def self.do_something
    puts 'foo!'
  end
end

do_something # => undefined local variable or method `do_something' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: You say you want to define a module that can be 'included in any class', but in your example you aren't including it in the place you're trying to call it at all. Do you really mean "any" class, or do you really mean you want it to be somehow included in _every_ class? In general, what you describe is not how ruby works, although there are various ways to do it, depending on what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @jrochkind  it's a confusing question because I'm confused, sorry!  Please see updated question.  An example that I have been studying is the [colored gem](https://github.com/defunkt/colored)

Comment: The colored gem monkey-patches (adds at runtime) methods into String. Note that you actually can't call it's methods "anywhere", you have to call them on a String class: `"a string".blue`, `some_string.blue`. This kind of monkey-patching is generally considered a bad idea though.  And still isn't what you're asking. If you really want to define a method that can be called "anywhere", don't define it in a module, just define it outside of any module or class at all, on the "top level".  But this is a bad idea, in addition to not being what the colored gem is doing which is also not a great idea

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "that isn't any class". `blue` is applied to an instance of the `String` class.

Comment: Ok got it -- the `String` class was modified.  Thus, it is still "included" in a class.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running it like this

```
module Example
  def do_something
    puts 'foo!'
  end
end

include Example
do_something #=> foo!
```